# Use composed map in AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper, function-composition

Suppose my AutoMapper configuration knows how to map from type T1 to type T2 and from T2 to type T3. I then have the following. It works:

```
public static class MapperExtensions
{
    public static T3 MapVia<T1, T2, T3>(this IMapper mapper, T1 t1) {
        var t2 = mapper.Map<T2>(t1);
        var t3 = mapper.Map<T3>(t2);
        return t3;
    }
    /// <summary> The calling code needs to ensure that t1 is of a type that the mapper knows how to map to type T2.</summary> 
    public static T3 MapVia<T2, T3>(this IMapper mapper, object t1) {
        var t2 = mapper.Map<T2>(t1);
        var t3 = mapper.Map<T3>(t2);
        return t3;
    }
}
```

My question is whether it is possible to bypass the middle type? I would love to be able to do something in my configuration to tell it "Generate a map from T1 to T3 that is the composition of your map from T1 to T2 and your map from T2 to T3." Then I could just map from T1 to T3 normally.

There are times when T2 is large, which may make this a performance issue. There are also cases where T2 is not particularly large.

Comment: There's nothing built in.

Answer (score 0):

Just converting Lucian Bargaoanu's comment to an answer here: There is no built-in way to do that.